# Linear formula in which all negative values are replaced by 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

I am looking for a mathetmatic expression for a linear formula such as y = x - 50, for which all negative values are replaced by zero, so that this part of the formula creates a horizontal line (y = 0) when plotted.

Comment: Do you mean something like $y=\max(0, x-50)$?

Comment: You mean $\max\{x-50, 0\}$?

Comment: "Linear" does not cope well with being zero twice and then non-zero somewhere else. Perhaps, though, you can go with $x-50+\lvert x-50\rvert$ (id est, what others have already written, but in disguise).

Comment: Thank you very much for such quick replies! This was indeed precisely what I needed. Thanks.